# Symfony authentifcation through LDAP doesn't work with login form

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, ldap

I've some trouble with LDAP authentication with a custom login form, however it works perfectly with the http_basic_ldap so it's not an error of LDAP.

My files :
**app/config/security.yml**

```
security:
providers:
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: ldap
            base_dn: ou=People,dc=insa-toulouse,dc=fr
            search_dn: ~
            search_password: ~
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: uid

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login_firewall:
        pattern:   ^/login$
        anonymous: ~
    main:
        logout:
            path: /logout
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
            service: ldap
            dn_string: 'uid={username},ou=People,dc=insa-toulouse,dc=fr'
        #anonymous: true
        #http_basic_ldap:
        #    service: ldap
        #    dn_string: 'uid={username},ou=People,dc=insa-toulouse,dc=fr'
    default:
        anonymous: ~
```

Note that commented http basic works perfectly !

**app/config/services.yml**

```
services:
ldap:  
    class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient
    arguments:
        - srv-ldap
```

**Controller/SecurityController.php**

```
        <?php

    namespace ClubInfo\PizzaBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

    class SecurityController extends Controller
    {
            /**
             * @Route("/login", name="login")
             */
            public function loginAction(Request $request)
            {
                    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

                    // get the login error if there is one
                    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

                    // last username entered by the user
                    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

                    return $this->render(
                            'ClubInfoPizzaBundle:security:login.html.twig',
                            array(
                                    // last username entered by the user
                                    'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                                    'error'         => $error,
                            )
                    );
            }
    }
```

and **Resources/views/security/login.html.twig**

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

Thank you for answers ;)

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Is there an error message? Or what does it do? What's in the Symfony log files when the issue happens? What does your `access_control` section look like?

Comment: @ChadSikorra Sorry for necrobumping this topic, but no solutions found so far, and I have the exact same setup and problem as OP.   When using `Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient`in the service definition I have the message `Could not complete search with dn "dc=domaine,dc=local", query "(sAMAccountName=mylogin)" and filters "*"`. When using `Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap` the error is completely different and seems more core dependant. `[...]Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap::__construct() must be an instance of of Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\AdapterInterface [...]`. I'm lost..

Comment: @Stéphane What version of Symfony do you use? It might be best to start a new question anyway. There's a lot of factors as to where it might be getting tripped up (also depends on if this is AD or OpenLDAP). I actually have resorted to my own bundle ([LdapToolsBundle](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle)) in most cases, as the configuration is much more straight-forward.

Comment: @ChadSikorra I'm using Symfony 3.2. I'm pretty sure the use of external bundle won't be approved. I guess I'll start a new question. Thank you for your help!